# How can I write Tableau instead of Table in caption?

Tags: tables, languages

I want to change Table in English into Tableau in French. How can I do so?

Here is the code I'm using.

```
\documentclass[french]{report}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|c}
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
Mot & Chiffre \\
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
B & 2 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mots et chiffres  }
\end{center}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you really get the English name at the moment? That is surprising... ?

Comment: try `\begin{document}\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tableau}`

Comment: @Bernard thank you it did work too, but I can't get back to small caps?

Comment: @Bernard why you modified \being{center} to \centering? is it better? simpler? or something else?

Comment: What do you mean? No small caps? For your other question: the table environment already adds some vertical spacing around the table, and `center` adds *some more*, which normally is unwanted. `\centering` does not add anything.

Comment: I always get TABLEAU, while I'd rather get Tableau.

Comment: @Bernard I always get TABLEAU, while I'd rather get Tableau.

Comment: Just remove `\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}`. Note that French typographical tradition is to use small caps (and an `emdash` instead of a colon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. If you want to keep the default small caps for ‘Tableau’, you can use the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[french]{report}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=sc}
\def\frenchtablename{Tableau}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|c}
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
Mot & Chiffre \\
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
B & 2 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\hline
C & 33 \\
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mots et chiffres }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]